# Construct matrix from vector elements in simulink

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector, block, simulink

I have a vector signal in Simulink that contains

`[x1,x2,x3]`

I want to multiply this vector with a matrix that is constructed from its elements, given by

`M=[0 x3 x2; x1 0 x3; x1 x2 0]`

Is there a block in simulink that allows me to create this matrix efficiently? The vector is dynamic, so importing the matrix from the workspace is not an option. The 'Selector' block comes close, but it does not allow the matrix to contain constants.

Comment: Are you stuck on creating the matrix or computing the multiplication? The multiplication is trivial with the `product` block...

Comment: @Wolfie creating the matrix, multiplication cant happen otherwise

Answer (score 3):

There's no single block for this, but we can create the matrix from selector and concatenation blocks:

[image: block diagram]

1. Prefix the input vector `[1 2 3]` with a zero so that we can select it.
2. Use `Selector` blocks to create the rows of the output matrix
3. Use the `Matrix Concatenate` block to combine the rows (cat on dimension 1)
4. Output...

The selectors look like this, with varying indexing vectors. Note that in your case changing the "Index Mode" to zero-based might make some sense because of the `0` concatenation, but generally MATLAB is one-based so I've left the default alone...

You can also change the "Index Option" to use an addition input port for your indexing vector if you want to make this more dynamic.

[image: selector]

Comment: Thanks very much, I was trying something similar. It's unfortunate that Simulink does not have a block for this, it's very common to these kind of operations for transformations

Comment: You can always create an S-Function block and write the transformation in MATLAB code...